# How to clip a line using circle and triangle clipping windows?

Tags: graphics

While using Cohen-Sutherland line clipping algorithm, the clipping window is a rectangle. Is it possible to clip a line using a triangular or circular windows using a similar technique?

Answer (score 1):

The idea can be reused for clipping against a triangle, with seven regions instead of nine. You can easily see what pair of origin/destination regions result in no visibility or full visibility. For the remaining cases deeper analysis is required.

For circles the coding is of less use because two "outside" codes are not enough to decide. But clipping a segment against a circle is simple: write the parametric equation of the segment and find the values of the parameter giving a point inside the circle (this amounts to the resolution of a quadratic equation).